# Ordenar arreglo dependiendo el año

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código, lo que quiero que haga es que me `ordene` el arreglo dependiendo del año, con sus registros en la misma tabla, donde se tienen todos los registros de quejas, entonces los del año `2017` están recorriendo a los del `2016`.

Ejemplo, del 2017 se tienen 190 quejas, se supone que del 2016 se cuentan con 322, al acomodar o mostrar el numero de queja del 2016 en vez de que sea la 1 me dice que es la 191, que es el consecutivo del 2017 de la ultima queja, estoy tratando de separar por año y el orden consecutivo para que me de el número correcto. 2017 4=>[1],5=>[2],6=>[3], etc y del 2016 2=>[1],5=>[2],7=>[3],11=>[4] etc...

**Código**

```
    $sql = "SELECT  IdTipo, IdAgraviado, IdExpediente, NoExpediente,  
             year(fecha) as aaa, fecha FROM tExpedientes WHERE IdTipo=1 
             and Reg_Folio = Reg_Folio ORDER BY IdTipo, aaa DESC, 
             IdAgraviado, IdExpediente, NoExpediente DESC";

$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($version === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$array = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST)) {

    array_push($array,$row['IdExpediente']);

}
//print_r($array);
if( empty( $array )){
    echo "1";
}elseif

    ($valor=array_search($_GET['aaa'],$array)=2016){
    if($valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)!=0){
        $valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)+1;
        echo "$valor";
    }

} elseif ($valor=array_search($_GET['aaa'],$array)=2017) {
    //print_r($valor);
    if($valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)!=0){
    $valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)+1;
    echo "$valor";

  } 
}
```

Espero y puedan auxiliarme o de plano decirme que no se puede hacer así, espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entendí nada sobre la explicación de lo que quieres. Sería mucho más fácil si pusieras valores de prueba y el resultado deseado

Comment: Oh, una disculpa, por no explicarme

Comment: sería mejor que pusieras ejemplos de datos y resultado que quieres

Comment: Una disculpa, lo que esta en azul es del año 2016, si vemos el registro 2 tiene el 190 en vez de que me muestre el 190 que me muestre el 1

Answer (score 0):

Es un tanto confusa tu pregunta y no queda para nada claro el resultado que quieres optener. Básicamente lo que yo entiendo es que quieres separar los registros por fechas.

Bien puedes crear un Array multidimensional para tal efecto, algo como esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT  IdTipo, IdAgraviado, IdExpediente, NoExpediente,  
         year(fecha) as aaa, fecha FROM tExpedientes WHERE IdTipo=1 
         and Reg_Folio = Reg_Folio ORDER BY IdTipo, aaa DESC, 
         IdAgraviado, IdExpediente, NoExpediente DESC";

$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($version === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$array = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST)) {

// Creas el Array con un índice por años 
$array [$row['aaa']][ ] = $row['IdExpediente'];

} 

print_r( $array );
```

Así tendrías un Array de Arrays separados por fechas.

**1° Edición**

También puedes pasar toda la fila, si es lo que necesitas, en el while:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST)) {

// pasas la fila ($row) completa 
$array [$row['aaa']][ ] = $row;

}
```

**2° Edición**

Puedes recorrer el Array con uno o 2 foreach dependiendo lo que busques

```
foreach ( $array as $ano => $filas)
{
    echo $ano;

    foreach ( $filas as $key => $row )
    { 
        echo ++$key;
        print_r ( $row );
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias y una disculpa por no saber explicarme, en la imagen creo que se ve un poco mas claro, deja intento y te comento como va

Comment: te muestro el resultado de la consulta antes de imprimir;

Comment: Número de queja: Array ( [2017] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 9 [6] => 10 [7] => 11 [8] => 12 [9] => 13 [10] => 14 [11] => 15 [12] => 16 [13] => 17 [14] => 18 [15] => 19 [16] => 20 [17] => 21 [18] => 22 [19] => 23 [20] => 24 [21] => 25 [22] => 26 [23] => 27 [24] => 28 [25]  [2016] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 12 [7] => 16 [8] => 17 [9] => 18 [10] => 24 [11] => 28 [12] => 29 [13] => 32 [14] => 38 [15] => 40 [16] => 45 [17] => 47 [18] =>

Comment: @Cesar Ortega ¿Qué imagen? Tal como te puse puedes agrupar los resultados. Aún sigo sin saber exactamente que es lo quieres hacer o conseguir. Edita tu pregunta e intenta exponer el problema aportando más detalles y datos.

Comment: Hola gracias @Xerif por tu ayuda, como te muestro en la parte de arriba lo que necesito es acomodar los registro dependiendo de si es queja y contar cuantas de ellas hay para mostrar el numero de la queja segun sea el orden y con tu ayuda, ya lo hace `$array [$row['aaa']][ ] = $row['IdExpediente'];` ahora solo me falta que me muestre cuando haces la consulta del expediente el numero de queja correspodiente por orden segun este acomodada, no se si me di a entender. y con respecto a la imagen la subi pero se elimino porque no aportaba.

Comment: @Cesar Ortega te he añadido un ejemplo de como pasar la fila completa. Si te sirvió la respuesta marcala como aceptada.

Comment: Hola, @Xerif, lo que me sirve mas es acomodar por años el orden cronologico de los expedientes con queja, lo que aun no encuentro es como mostrar en el expediente el numero que le corresponde, lo estoy tratando de hacer con un if, te muestro; `if ($valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)!=0){
$valor=array_search($_GET['folio'],$array)+1;
echo "$valor";` lo que trato es ver el folio que trae y si es queja asignarle el numero consecutivo que le corresponde, segun el folio.

Comment: Por que no recorres recorres con un foreach?? Te edito la respuesta y te pongo un ejemplo.